# jQuery iframe html() null

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, null

I am making a script for a webpage of mine, where I use jquery to upload files using a hidden iframe. After the uploading is done, the PHP script, that I use for uploading, "echoes" a JSON String. To watch that string I do :

```
$("#myform").submit(function () {
    $("#myframe").load(function () {
        alert ($(this).contents().text());
    });
});
```

This works properly, but when I try to use `html()`, instead of `text()`, I get null instead of the iframe's contents. Why that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the JSON with a `text/plain` MIME type? If so, why would the browser parse this as HTML? If you're sending text, don't expect to receive HTML.